# Are conformal maps between Riemannian manifolds real-analytic?

Tags: real-analysis, riemannian-geometry, analyticity, conformal-geometry, analytic-functions

> Let $M,N$ be oriented smooth ($C^{\infty}$) $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifolds, and let $f:M \to N$ be a smooth orientation-preserving weakly* conformal map.
>
> Do there exist real-analytic structures on $M,N$ that make $f$ real-analytic?

I only assume that the metrics are $C^{\infty}$.
Note that every smooth manifold [has a unique real-analytic structure](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8789/can-every-manifold-be-given-an-analytic-structure) (up to diffeomorphism) compatible with the smooth structure.

A  reasonable starting point would be to know whether every $C^{\infty}$ conformal map between real-analytic manifolds with real-analytic Riemannian metrics is real-analytic. (but what I am asking seems much harder).

*A weakly conformal map is a map whose differential at every point is either conformal or zero. (This is equivalent to $df^Tdf =(\det df)^{\frac{2}{n}} \, \text{Id}_{TM}$).

*Motivation:*

I am trying to understand [if smooth weakly conformal maps whose differential vanishes at a point are constant](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/308102/a-conformal-map-whose-jacobian-vanishes-at-a-point-is-constant) (for dimension $n \ge 3$). This [seems to be the case for analytic maps](https://mathoverflow.net/a/308673/46290), hence my current interest in the possible analyticity of such maps.

---

For the Euclidean case, I this follows directly by [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(conformal_mappings)):

For $n=2$, every such map is complex-analytic. Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open subset, $n \ge 3$, and let $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth conformal map. By Liouville's theorem, $f$ is of the form
$$ f(x)=b+\alpha\frac{1}{|x-a|^\epsilon}A(x-a),$$

where $A$ is an orthogonal matrix, and $\epsilon \in \{0,2\}, b \in \mathbb{R}^n,\alpha \in \mathbb{R},a \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \Omega$.

So, up to translations and dilations, the only non-obvious to handle is
$$ f(x)=\frac{A x}{|x|^2}, 0 \notin \Omega.$$

which is real-analytic as a multiplication of two analytic maps. ($1/x^2$ is analytic on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$).

Comment: Actually, the question doesn't make sense the way you phrased it. It's true that every smooth manifold has a real-analytic structure, but it's not unique in the sense that you need it to be. Given two real-analytic atlases on $M$, say $\mathscr A_1$ and $\mathscr A_2$, there's a real-analytic diffeomorphism from $(M,\mathscr A_1)$ to $(M,\mathscr A_2)$. But the _identity map_ might not be analytic between these two structures. So a specific conformal diffeomorphism might be analytic with respect to one pair of analytic atlases, but not with respect to another.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that what is true is that if $M$ and $N$ are real-analytic manifolds (i.e., with *specific* real-analytic atlases) endowed with *real-analytic Riemannian metrics*, then any conformal map from $M$ to $N$ is real-analytic. But I haven't found a reference.

Comment: Thank you, I agree that the question does not make sense as I phrased it. Just to be sure: Given a *specific* smooth atlas $A$ on a manifold $M$, let $A_1$ be a compatible real-analytic atlas (this just means a real-analytic "sub-atlas" , right?). If we compose $A_1$ with a smooth diffeomorphism of $(M,A)$ which is not real-analytic w.r.t $A_1$, do we get another real-analytic atlas which is compatible with $(M,A)$ and different from $A_1$?

Comment: (Also, I am actually interested in the case where the metrics are only $C^{\infty}$, but maybe this is too hopeful. I have edited the question according to your comments)

Comment: You're right -- any real-analytic atlas compatible with $A$ is a "sub-atlas" of $A$. And your idea about how to get a different analytic atlas also compatible with $(M,A)$ is also right.

Comment: About your motivating question -- First, the usual definition of conformal map includes the assumption that the differential is invertible at each point. Second, it's certainly not true that an analytic map whose differential vanishes at a point is constant -- consider, for example, the map $f:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C$ given by $f(z) = z^2$. What's true is that an analytic map that _vanishes to infinite order_ at a point must be constant (at least if the domain is connected).

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't careful enough about the terminology-I meant *weakly* conformal maps (the differential can be conformal or zero). I was aware of your example $z \to z^2$-the motivating question is for the case where the dimension is bigger than $2$.